# MPlayer not working after update

Tags: package-management, dependencies, ffmpeg, mplayer

After an update with update-manager in 12.04, MPlayer is not working anymore. It needs `ffmpeg`, but it can't be installed due to unmet dependencies. I added a PPA for `ffmpeg`, but did not solve the problem.

See output:

```
Python (v2.7) requires to install .... GStreamer ffmpeg video plugin. 
Codecs to play mpeg, divx, mpeg4, ac3, wmv and asf files.
```

Using install, I get an error messages that it can't be installed due to unmet dependencies. See list below:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg: Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 6:0.10.4.0ubuntu0jon2.2 is to be installed
                      Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
                      Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.2) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.16) but 1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Depends: libpostproc-extra-52 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libswscale-extra-2 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found the solution on web.

It is due to the installed PPA:

- https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg

Try to run the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
```

Then run totem and install the missing plugin

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that request contains gstremer plugins can be divided on i386 and x64 plugins.
If you deselect x64 if you have x86 linux or deselect i386 for x64 linux it would install with no conflicts.

Comment: How do you do that?